# Import \chapter into amsart

Tags: sectioning, chapters, amsthm, amsart, amsbook

I would like to create a document with the **appearance of `amsart`**, but with added **`\chapter` command** (styled as in `amsbook`, or differently). How can I do that?

I tried to make LaTeX load both `amsbook` and `amsart` by various combinations of `\LoadClass` and `\documentclass`, but it seems to be a failing strategy since they both define a lot of things using `\newcommand`, causing an infinity of errors.
I also realized I can't do it the other way around since I want to stick to the look of theorems as in `amsart` and not in `amsbook`.
I also know that I can, in theory, style it myself using `titlesec`, but it would be a lot of manual work to get the spacing of `amsart`'s titles, and I would like to avoid doing that manually.

A MWE is the following:

```
%\documentclass[openany,11pt]{amsbook}
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Fair Chapter}

\section{Lovely section}

\begin{theorem} % Should show "Theorem" in bold, unintended.
I love ducks.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd change the parts of `amsbook.cls` that are not of your liking. Adding just the infrastructure for chapters requires much more lines of code than those added by David Carlisle, because also the table of contents and the other listings should be taken into account.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\def\@secnumfont{\mdseries}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}

\patchcmd{\@thm}{\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headfont{\scshape}}{\thm@headfont{\bfseries}}{}{}

\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\section{Title of this section}
\subsection{Title of this subsection}

\begin{thm}
Whatever the theorem says.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Somebody]
Whatever the theorem says.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what I get if I remove `\chapter{Chapter title}`, the customizations and load `amsart` instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the lines relating to `\chapter` from amsbook

```
%\documentclass[openany,11pt]{amsbook}
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter

\def\chaptermark#1{}%whatever


\let\chapterrunhead\partrunhead

\def\chapter{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}\global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindenttrue \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth<\z@ \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \let\@secnumber\thechapter \fi
  \typeout{\chaptername\space\@secnumber}%
  \def\@toclevel{0}%
  \ifx\chaptername\appendixname \@tocwriteb\tocappendix{chapter}{#2}%
  \else \@tocwriteb\tocchapter{chapter}{#2}\fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \@makechapterhead{#2}\@afterheading}
\def\@schapter#1{\typeout{#1}%
  \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \def\@toclevel{0}%
  \ifx\chaptername\appendixname \@tocwriteb\tocappendix{chapter}{#1}%
  \else \@tocwriteb\tocchapter{chapter}{#1}\fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \@makeschapterhead{#1}\@afterheading}
\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \leavevmode \hskip-\leftskip
      \rlap{\vbox to\z@{\vss
          \centerline{\normalsize\mdseries
              \uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}
          \vskip 3pc}}\hskip\leftskip\fi
     #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\appendix{\par
  \c@chapter\z@ \c@section\z@
  \let\chaptername\appendixname
  \def\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}

\newcounter{chapter}

\newif\if@openright

\makeatother



\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}



\begin{document}

\chapter{My Fair Chapter}

\section{Lovely section}

\begin{theorem} % Should show "Theorem" in bold, unintended.
I love ducks.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: @egreg exercise for the reader, in the best pedagogical tradition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your useful answer above; I'm trying to do the same thing as the OP. I can't for the life of me determine what the correct lines are from amsbook for the table of contents. Should I be looking in the .dtx file somewhere?

Comment: @Mr.Chip you could just look in amsbook.cls, but despite the answer I posted above a better answer is "dont do this" why not use amsbook that has chapters already? just search for the string `chapter` the toc layout is `\def\l@chapter{\@tocline{0}{8pt plus1pt}{0pt}{}{}}`
\let\tocchapter\tocsection