# How to edit \part of amsart class?

Tags: sectioning, amsart, parts

I am not satisfied at all of how the `\part` command looks like in the amsart class.

In particular, I find much better how `\part` looks like in the standard article class.

Is there a way to mix the two? I would like a document in `amsart` with \part as in article.

I have tried to mix the two things, but I have not been able to come up with a solution (I have created a cls file, but I made some mistakes and the headings are not ok...). I have been following the tips from here 
[Import \chapter into amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241183/import-chapter-into-amsart) 
but it is not exactly what I am really looking for.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the definition of `article.cls`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
%default definition of article.cls
%using \renewcommand instead of \newcommand
\renewcommand\part{%
   \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
   \par
   \addvspace{4ex}%
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2%
     %%%\markboth{}{}\par}% removing redefinition of headings
     \par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \huge \bfseries #1\par}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{foo}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually it works but has the same problems of the solution I tried: it changes dramatically the headings! After the first \part the heading changes (and it remains only the page number). If you use plain amsart -without changing \part - the heading is longer with name of the author. Do you know how I could fix this? Shall I really use \fancy? Hope not... Thanks again.

Comment: @Romeo: Fixed it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! ;-)